# UICollectionView with an entire item and another exceeding - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm making an app which contains a `UITableView`, and inside this `UITableView`, there is a cell containing a horizontal `UICollectionView`.
Into this `UICollectionView`, I'm trying to display only one item, and a part of an other, to indicate to the user that he can scroll to the right.

Here is the result I would like to get :
[image: Wireframe 1]

But actually, here is what I get :

[image: Wireframe 2]

Here is my code :

```
extension CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        var width = self.frame.width - 32.0

        return CGSize(width: width, height: 275.0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

}
```

As you can see, the sizeForItem width is `self.frame.width - 32.0` and not `self.frame.width - 48.0`. I did this because my collectionView cell contains a container, which has a right spacing of 16.0pt with its superview.

Anyone has the solution to get the right behavior ?

Comment: How about using a leading (left) inset of 16?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to precise this, there is a leading of 16 on the collectionView, and I also tried left contentInset

Comment: That isn't consistent with the code you've presented.  You are returning `UIEdgeInsets.zero` from `insetForSectionAt`.  Try making those insets non-zero.  Also, you should be using `collectionView.bounds` instead of `self.frame` for calculating your item sizes.

Comment: Another idea: *I did this because my collectionView cell contains a container, which has a right spacing of 16.0pt with its superview.*  Move the 16pt spacing with the superview to the left side instead of the the right side.